# MismatchedInputException error Parsing Json

Tags: json, spring-boot, parsing, runtime-error

In spring boot I get the **MismatchedInputException** error while trying to parse this json

```
[
 {
"name": "abcd",
"number": "0.11258868"
 },
 {
"name": "try",
"number": "1.155866887"
 },
 {
"name": "test",
"number": "0.123444"
 }
]
```

My class is :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class Info {
private String name;
private double number;

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public Object getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(double number)
{
    this.number= number;
}
```

The mapping code is simply this:

```
@GetMapping
public String setInfo()
{
    var info= (List<Info>)m_restTemplate.getForObject(url, Info.class);

    return "test";
}
```

I know this is very simple code but I couldn't find the solution. What is mismatching with the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the retrieval part. You are getting a list of `Info`, but you are saying to Spring `RestTemplate` that it will get a single `Info`. Try the following:

```java
@GetMapping
public String setInfo() {
    var info = m_restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, 
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Info>>() {}).getBody();

    return "test";
}
```

Comment: Thank you actually it solved the error part but name returns as null. I didn't understand this method I will look at it.
But in my code I tried to get list of info as var states it. How does it mean I try to get single info?

Comment: Okey I solved the null part I was writing wrong setter method name. Btw it also works:
var info = m_restTemplate.getForObject(url, Info[].class);

Comment: May I ask you what topic should I work for this type of mistakes. I mean for example I couldn't guessed that Info[].class part was the problem. Is it reflection?

Comment: The thing is that `getForObject(url, Info.class)` gets you a single `Info`, but your JSON has a list of `Info`. That is why `getForObject(url, Info[].class)` works because now it is able to parse the JSON to an Arrya of `Info`. Read the documentation carefully and check some examples (https://www.baeldung.com/ is usually a good place to start).